# Fastest way to convert File to Stream

Tags: c#, filestream

I did google and see different ways to read and write a file but I need fastest way to convert file into a stream.

I am working on improving performance of a method which simply converts the file into stream. This will be called countless number of times daily and we are looking at improving it's performance. Please see below the method which I wrote.

```
public static Stream GetFileStream(string fileName)
{
   Stream result;
   try
   {
      if (File.Exists(fileName))
      {
          result = File.OpenRead(fileName);
          if (result.Length > 0)
          {
              result.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
          }
      }
      else
      {
         throw new Exception(string.Format("{0} file not found.", fileName));
      }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       throw ex;
   }
   return result;
}
```

The sample test calling code ( which I do not have control is like below)

```
List<string> fileNames = new List<string>();
//add almost 30,000 file names to string

List<Stream> fileStreams = new List<Stream>();
foreach(string fileName in fileNames)
{
   Stream fileStream = FileUtility.GetFileStream(fileName);
   fileStreams.Add(fileStream);
}
```

I am looking at how to improve performance of my method ConvertToStream.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE 1**

As per friends below, I converted my method like below

```
public static Stream ConvertToStream(string fileName)
{
   Stream result;
   try
   {
      result = File.OpenRead(fileName);        
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      throw ex;
   }
   return result;
}
```

I will let you know about performance.

**UPDATE 2**

I got reply from my callers saying that refactor code not break anything. We are looking to refactor code outside of this method. I feel this method is good. Thanks yaakov and everyone...

Comment: I don't see any reason to use this over calling `File.OpenRead` directly - the outer try/catch is redundant, the `File.Exists` check is mostly unnecessary since `OpenRead` will throw (a more precise exception) if the file does not exist. The stream will already be located at the beginning so the `Seek` is not required.

Comment: I don't think seeking to the beginning of the file after opening is necessary. The stream should start at the beginning of the file when opened.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into these comments.

Comment: I don't know what the use case is exactly, but having 30,000 files open simultaneously seems a little twitchy. I usually open a file, process it, close it, repeat for the next file.

Comment: I'm confused by your `GetFileStream` method. Why do you check if the file exists before opening it, only to throw an exception if it doesn't? Why not just try to open the file and let the exception that's thrown when it doesn't exist bubble up (or if needs be, catch it, wrap it, throw a new one - it's the exceptional case, not the expected case). Why do you seek to 0? What leads you to think that the file won't be opened at 0? Why do you have `throw ex;` around everything? I assume this is to hide the stack trace of any exceptions thrown within this method, but why?

Comment: _`My method needs to return Stream not FileStream`_: [`Stream`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/stream.cs#L45) is an abstract base class. [`FileStream`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/filestream.cs#L396) is a concrete class of `Stream`. In short: you can't create `Stream`, you can only create concrete classes such as `FileStream`. `Stream a = File.OpenRead(fileName);` works (obviously).

Comment: I don't understand what is being asked here. As @John_ReinstateMonica said `FileStream` *is* `Stream` so no need to do anything beyond `return File.OpenRead(fileName);`. Side note: separately checking for file existence does not simplify the code as it still can fail with "file not found" if file is gone immediately after the check...

Comment: And now you've changed the question into just post without question at all... Not sure how that makes *a clear question*...

Comment: Alexei... My question is always same. I wrote a method to return FileStream and posted here to get advice on improving performance and people started engaging discussion. Sometimes I do not understand after people understood the questions started meaning answers and discussion someone comes and defines and saying it is not clear,,, whatever...

Comment: _"we need to make sure the pointer is at the beginning in our stream"_ - This really doesn't make sense to me. Why on Earth are you doing this? The file will open at  0...

Comment: My technical achitect gave a functional requirement document and in that see I one bullet point under acceptance criteria saying make sure pointer is set at beginning and caller simply tries to start reading file from beginning.

Comment: The operating system takes care of that for you, it's not something your application needs to concern itself with, unless you were to do things like re-use streams.

Comment: Perhaps you could try to explain to the technical architect that this isn't necessary?

Comment: Doing that John.

Comment: It is necessary to return a Stream with the correct position.  File.OpenRead already does that for you.  If you had copied the bytes to a MemoryStream, explicitly repositioning the stream would have been required.  Ie the specification is correct.

Comment: I got reply from my callers saying that refactor code not break anything. We are looking to refactor code outside of this method. I feel this method is good. Thanks yaakov and everyone...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public static Stream GetFileStream(string fileName) => File.OpenRead(fileName);
```

The rest of your code is largely redundant:

- The outer `try`/`catch` rethrows the existing exception, though it destroys the stack trace in the process.
- If the file doesn't exist, `File.OpenRead` will throw a `FileNotFoundException` already. You don't need to do this check yourself, and doing so allows room for a race condition anyway, if the file gets deleted between calls to `File.Exists` and `File.OpenRead`.
- A newly opened file stream will start at the beginning of the file, so there is no need to `Seek` to the start.

Comment: File.OpenRead is returning FileStream. My functional requirement is to send Stream back.

Comment: @Ziggler The method in yaakov's answer returns `Stream`. Did you even try it?

Comment: I am trying it. I will give my library to guy who is testing, Please see my updates in my question

Comment: @Ziggler `FileStream` inherits from `Stream`, you can return a `FileStream` from any method that expects to return a plain `Stream`

Comment: I will accept this as answer since it gave me explanation about my code and helped me to remove unused redundant code...

Comment: I will still keep post my updates.

Comment: I got reply from my callers saying that refactor code not break anything. We are looking to refactor code outside of this method. I feel this method is good. Thanks yaakov and everyone...

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with the `FileStream` [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_FileStream__ctor_System_String_System_IO_FileMode_)?

Do note, that File I/O is never "fast".  You can do things in a more efficient manner, sure, but File I/O is often one of the slower parts of an application.